# mod_rewrite url with 1 or 2 params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

URL: `http://example.com/good_game/osmp/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?service=$1&terminal=$2 [L,QSA]
```

i receive

```
Array ( [service] => good_game [terminal] => osmp )
```

it's ok, but

URL: `http://example.com/good_game` or  `http://example.com/good_game/`

i need

```
Array ( [service] => good_game)
```

and it return 404 not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for both:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?$ /?service=$1&terminal=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Will match:

```
http://example.com/good_game/osmp/
http://example.com/good_game/osmp
http://example.com/good_game/
http://example.com/good_game
```